# CircleCi build failed on Yii2 application

Tags: composer-php, yii2, circleci

is the first time i use [circleCi](https://circleci.com) (and Yii2), and i am facing a problem related to composer: 
[here you can see the build](https://circleci.com/gh/solaechea/yii2test/1)

As you can see composer can't find the package for php >= 5.4.0. So the build fails.

> cebe/markdown 1.0.1 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.

what i can do here? i searched on the web without success.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

Based on a message from circleCi site:

> We didn't find a circle.yml for this build. You can specify deployment or override our inferred test steps from a circle.yml checked in to your repo's root directory.

I created a circle.yml file and added the following configuration

```
machine:
   php:
      version: 5.5.11
```

And my composer.json looks like this (default for yii2 advanced template):

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Application Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "application template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

after that, builds executed successfully

Thanks